# Iterating over big arrays with limited memory and time of execution

Tags: ruby, performance, testng, out-of-memory

I’m having trouble using Ruby to pass some tests that make the array too big and return an error.

> ```
> Solution.rb: failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
> ```

I have failed to pass it twice.

The problem is about scheduling meetings. The method receives two parameters in order: a matrix with all the first days that investors can meet in the company, and a matrix with all the last days.

For example:

```
firstDay = [1,5,10]
lastDay = [4,10,10]
```

This shows that the first investor will be able to find himself between the days `1..4`, the second between the days `5..10` and the last one in `10..10`.

I need to return the largest number of investors that the company will serve. In this case, all of them can be attended to, the first one on day 1, the second one on day 5, and the last one on day 10.

So far, the code works normally, but with some hidden tests with at least 1000 investors, the error I mentioned earlier appears.

Is there a best practice in Ruby to handle this?

My current code is:

```rb
def countMeetings(firstDay, lastDay)
    GC::Profiler.enable
    GC::Profiler.clear

    first = firstDay.sort.first
    last = lastDay.sort.last
    available = []
    
    #Construct the available days for meetings
    firstDay.each_with_index do |d, i|
        available.push((firstDay[i]..lastDay[i]).to_a)
    end
    available = available.flatten.uniq.sort
    investors = {}
    attended_day = []
    attended_investor = []

    #Construct a list of investor based in their first and last days
    firstDay.each_index do |i|
        investors[i+1] = (firstDay[i]..lastDay[i]).to_a
    end

    for day in available
        investors.each do |key, value|
            next if attended_investor.include?(key)
            if value.include?(day)
                next if attended_day.include?(day)
                attended_day.push(day)
                attended_investor.push(key)
            end
        end
    end

    attended_investor.size
end
```

Using `Lazy` as far as I could understand, I escaped the `MemoryError`, but I started receiving a runtime error:

> ```
> Your code was not executed on time. Allowed time: 10s
> ```

And my code look like this:

```rb
def countMeetings(firstDay, lastDay)

    loop_size = firstDay.size
    first = firstDay.sort.first
    last = lastDay.sort.last

    daily_attendance = {}
   
    (first..last).each do |day|
        for ind in 0...loop_size
            (firstDay[ind]..lastDay[ind]).lazy.each do |investor_day|
                next if daily_attendance.has_value?(ind)
                if investor_day == day
                    daily_attendance[day] = ind
                end
            end
        end
    end

    daily_attendance.size
end
```

And it went through the cases with few investors. I thought about using multi-thread and the code became the following:

```rb
 def countMeetings(firstDay, lastDay)

    loop_size = firstDay.size
    first = firstDay.sort.first
    last = lastDay.sort.last
    threads = []
    daily_attendance = {}
   
    (first..last).lazy.each_slice(25000) do |slice|
        slice.each do |day|
            threads << Thread.new do
                for ind in 0...loop_size
                    (firstDay[ind]..lastDay[ind]).lazy.each do |investor_day|
                        next if daily_attendance.has_value?(ind)
                        if investor_day == day
                            daily_attendance[day] = ind
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    threads.each{|t| t.join}
    daily_attendance.size
end
```

Unfortunately, it went back to the `MemoryError`.

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is trying to do, but perhaps you're instantiating very large arrays. Consider using [Enumerator::Lazy](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to avoid building large arrays, or build a Hash rather than an Array.

Comment: You code returns 3. Should it be only 2 on day 10? The day attendee count I get is `{1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>1, 7=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1, 10=>2}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done without consuming any more memory than the range of days. The key is to *avoid Arrays* and keep things as [Enumerators](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) as much as possible.

First, rather than the awkward pair of Arrays that need to be converted into Ranges, pass in an Enumerable of [Ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html). This both simplifies the method, and it allows it to be [Lazy](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator/Lazy.html) if the list of ranges is very large. It could be read from a file, fetched from a database or an API, or generated by another lazy enumerator. This saves you from requiring big arrays.

Here's an example using an Array of Ranges.

```
p count_meetings([(1..4), (5..10), (10..10)])
```

Or to demonstrate transforming your `firstDay` and `lastDay` Arrays into a lazy Enumerable of Ranges...

```
firstDays = [1,5,10]
lastDays = [4,10,10]
p count_meetings(
  firstDays.lazy.zip(lastDays).map { |first,last|
    (first..last)
  }
)
```

`firstDays.lazy` makes everything that comes after lazy. `.zip(lastDays)` iterates through both Arrays in pairs: [1,4], [5,10], and [10,10]. Then we turn them into Ranges. Because it's lazy it will only map them as needed. This avoids making another big Array.

---

Now that's fixed, all we need to do is iterate over each Range and increment their attendance for the day.

```
def count_meetings(attendee_ranges)
  # Make a Hash whose default values are 0.
  daily_attendance = Hash.new(0)

  # For each attendee
  attendee_ranges.each { |range|
    # For each day they will attend, add one to the attendance for that day.
    range.each { |day| daily_attendance[day] += 1 }
  }
  
  # Get the day/attendance pair with the maximum value, and only return the value.
  daily_attendance.max[1]
end
```

Memory growth is limited to how big the day range is. If the earliest attendee is on day 1 and the last is on day 1000 daily_attendance is just 1000 entries which is a long time for a conference.

And since you've built the whole Hash anyway, why waste it? Write one function that returns the full attendance, and another that extracts the max.

```
def count_meeting_attendance(attendee_ranges)
  daily_attendance = Hash.new(0)

  attendee_ranges.each { |range|
    range.each { |day| daily_attendance[day] += 1 }
  }
  
  return daily_attendance
end

def max_meeting_attendance(*args)
  count_meeting_attendance(*args).max[1]
end
```

---

Since this is an exercise and you're stuck with the wonky arguments, we can do the same trick and lazily zip `firstDays` and `lastDays` together and turn them into Ranges.

```
def count_meeting_attendance(firstDays, lastDays)
  attendee_ranges = firstDays.lazy.zip(lastDays).map { |first,last|
    (first..last)
  }

  daily_attendance = Hash.new(0)
  attendee_ranges.each { |range|
    range.each { |day| daily_attendance[day] += 1 }
  }
  
  return daily_attendance
end
```

Comment: I didn't understand it all, but I understood what I need to do, thank you sm. 
You were very didactic.

Comment: @JoaoPhelippe Any particular bit you need more help with?

Comment: Joao, I expect `Hash.new(0)` may be causing you some confusion. See the doc for the version of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument called the *default value*. Suppose `h = Hash.new(0)`, making `h`'s default value zero. All that means is that if `h` does not have a key `k` `h[k]` returns zero, which I'll write `h[k] #=> 0`. Let's add a key-value pair: `h[:dog] = 1`. Then `h #=> { :dog=>1 }` and `h[:dog] #=> 1`, Since `h` does not have a key `:cat`, `h[:cat] #=> 0`...

Comment: ...Suppose now we  write `h[:dog] += 1`. That's the same as `h[:dog] = h[:dog] + 1`, which equals `h[:dog] = 1 + 1 #=> 2`. Similarly,  `h[:cat] += 1` is the same as `h[:cat] = h[:cat] + 1`, and because `h[:cat]` on the right returns zero, `h[:cat] `is set equal to `1` (`0 + 1`) and `h #=> { :dog=>2, :cat=>1 }`. When a hash is defined in this way it is sometimes called a *counting hash*. It's effectively the same as `h = {}; [1,3,1,2,2].each do |n|; h[n] = 0 unless h.key?(n); h[n] += 1; end; h #=> {1=>2, 3=>1, 2=>2}`.

Comment: I updated my trouble. Just to clarify, this is a test to obtain a score on a given platform. But I already missed the deadline, so I want to resolve it for peace of mind.

Comment: @JoaoPhelippe Your approach will be abysmally slow. You're sorting both sets of investors, then looping through each day, then each investor, then each day again. If there's 1000 investors spanning 100 days that's 100 * 1000 * 100 or 10 million operations. Threads will not help. None of that is necessary, as shown above. Since this is an exercise, I'll edit the answer to demonstrate how to efficiently transform the weird arguments into a more sensible Enumerable of Ranges.

Comment: @JoaoPhelippe I've also added comments explaining the code. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Schwern Sorry to keep bothering you, I made this "Drawing" https://ibb.co/v4cY90b to be able to reason better. Could you please tell me what part of your code checks for if a certain day is already busy?

Comment: @JoaoPhelippe It doesn't. Mine assumes the investors will attend all days and simply counts them up to find the maximum number to expect on any day; the day with the biggest overlap. Your problem statement is not clear, can you only handle one investor per day?

Comment: @Schwern Yes, only one meeting by day. If two investors are going to stay in the schedule for only one day, only one of them can attend to the meeting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218164/discussion-between-joaophelippe-and-schwern).